# Autofac Owned instances equivalent without referencing the DLL

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I have units of work created by factory in my Dal project which I want to dispose of.

I've read I could make my units of work instances that are injected by Autofac `Disposable` by my code by adding `Owned<>`

My problem is that I don't want my Dal to reference Autofac.

Any way around this?

Comment: You should be able to configure Autofac to release components using a *lifetime scope*. See section 13.2.1 of [my book](http://amzn.to/12p90MG) for more details.

Comment: [As Mark Says - and definitely get the book, it's so much more than a DI containers user manual] OOTB Autofac will Dispose things in Lifetime Scoe when the lifetime ends without any extra work or e.g. referencing in the DAL. For that to Just Work, you simply need to have the UOWs be resolved via Autofac without any specific referencing of Autofac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register the service you don't want to be disposed as:

```
builder.RegisterType<SomeComponent>().ExternallyOwned();
```

The full details are here: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html#disabling-disposal

Comment: ... and then you can ask for a `Func<UOW> uowFactory` in your ctor and do a `use uow = _uowFactory()` in your code

Comment: I added externally owned for both my unit of work and for the context which is inside. The first http request works great, yet the second is throwing exception, saying the action could not be made because the context is disposed.. Any idea? I'm clueless

Comment: @S.Peter that suggests one or more of two things a) you have a long lived component (is it a singleton?) and b) someone is disposing stuff - if it's not you and you've eliminated cause (a) then you havent successfully marked all relevant pieces externally owned

Comment: The class that holds the unit of work factory is singleton, how is it effecting? And I've registered my unit of work as per dependency, dbcontext perLifetimeScope, repositories (in unit of work) perLifetimeScope. What could be wrong?

Comment: Singleton should not hold unit of work, because then it outlives its dependency, aka [Captive Dependency](blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).

Comment: It's bad to hold a factory of unit of works in singleton? How can I do it than? My class has to be singleton

Comment: You can hold Func of unit of work in a singleton. But I need more info to suggest a useful solution.

Comment: Please see my fully described question with code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35579140/autofac-disposal-issues