# Autofac registration and disposal issues

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm using entity framework 6 and Autofac in my web application.

I inject unit of work with DbContext inside, both externally owned so I can dispose them myself.

DbContext  registered PerLifetimeScope,

Unit of work is a factory, therefore registered as per dependency.

When Executing the first http Get action everthing works fine and I see the unit of work with the context are disposed after the response is coming from the db which is great.

My issue is that whenever I execute a second request, the context for some reason is disposed before I return an IQueryable. Therefore I get an execption saying:

> The operation could not be executed because the DbContext is disposed.

For example - calling the GetFolders method works the first time, and afterwards fails..

I see the context is disposed too early, what I don't understand is what triggers it too soon in the second request..

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    bool Commit();
}

public EFUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    public IRepository<Folder> FoldersRepository {get; set;}

    public IRepository<Letter> LettersRepository {get; set;}

    private readonly DbContext _context;


    public EFUnitOfWork(DbContext context, IRepository<Folder> foldersRepo, IRepository<Letter> lettersRepo)
    {
        _context = context;
        _foldersRepo = foldersRepo;
        LettersRepository = lettersRepo;
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }

            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public bool Commit()
    {
        try
        {
            return SaveChanges() > 0;
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException exc)
        {
            // just to ease debugging
            foreach (var error in exc.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var errorMsg in error.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, "Error trying to save EF changes - " + errorMsg.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }

            return false;
            throw exc;
        }
    }   
}



public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    protected readonly DbContext Context;
    protected readonly DbSet<T> DbSet;

    public EFRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Get()
    {
        return DbSet;
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        DbSet.Add(item);
    }

    public virtual Remove(T item)
    {
        DbSet.Remove(item);
    }

    public void Update(T item)
    {
        Context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public T FindById(int id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id); 
    }
}

public class DataService : IDataService
{
    private Func<IUnitOfWork> _unitOfWorkFactory;

    public (Func<IUnitOfWork> unitOfWorkFactory)
    {
        _unitOfWorkFactory = unitOfWorkFactory;             
    }

    public List<FolderPreview> GetFolders()
    {
        using(unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkFactory())
        {
            var foldersRepository = unitOfWork.FoldersRepository;

            var foldersData = foldersRepository.Get().Select(p => new FolderPreview
                                {
                                    Id = p.Id,
                                    Name = p.Name
                                }).ToList();

            return foldersData;
        }
    }
}

public class FolderPreview
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public string Name {get; set;}
}


Startup code:

{
    _container.RegisterGeneric<IRepository<>,Repository<>>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    _container.RegisterType<IDataService, DataService>().SingleInstance();
    _container.RegisterType<EFUnitOfWork, IUnitOfWork>().PerDepnendecny().ExternallyOwned();
    _container.RegisterType<DbContext, MyDbContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope().ExternallyOwned(); 
}
```

Is this related to singletons some how? Almost all of my application is singletons, the DataService is also Singleton. Anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: How is `unitOfWorkFactory` configured?

Comment: I've never used `AutoFac`, so I'm not posting an answer, but are you sure your `IRepository` and your `IUnitOfWork` are being injected the same context? Are you using the container's `BeginLifeTimeScope()` to make sure it's not creating a different instance for each?

Comment: Lifetime scope is created for each request that is made from what I know, so I'm pretty sure the context is similar for every request.. I only Begin LifetimeScope when resolving my Application root layer.

Comment: @S.Peter then it makes sense: you are using the disposed dbcontext. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are instancing only one `Repository` and one `DbContext` per request, but are instancing one new `IUnitOfWork` every time.

So when you call `GetFolders` you are creating a new `IUnitOfWork` and disposing it (which disposes the `DbContext` -on `IUnitOfWork.Dispose()`-): so when you call `GetFolders` again, when you create a second `IUnitOfWork`, since it's the same lifetime scope, it's injecting the already-created repository and the already-created `DbContext`, which is disposed (the container doesn't try to create a new instance since you are on the same lifetime scope)...

So on the second call, your `Repository` and `IUnitOfWork` are trying to use the disposed instance of `DbContext`, thus the error you are seeing.

---

As a solution, you can just not dispose the `DbContext` on `IUnitOfWork`, and dispose it only at the end of your request... or you could even not dispose it at all: this may sound strange, but [check this post](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html)

I'm copying the important part in case the link goes dead, by Diego Vega:

> The default behavior of DbContext is that the underlying connection is automatically opened any time is needed and closed when it is no longer needed. E.g. when you execute a query and iterate over query results using “foreach”, the call to IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() will cause the connection to be opened, and when later there are no more results available, “foreach” will take care of calling Dispose on the enumerator, which will close the connection. In a similar way, a call to DbContext.SaveChanges() will open the connection before sending changes to the database and will close it before returning.
>
> Given this default behavior, in many real-world cases it is harmless to leave the context without disposing it and just rely on garbage collection.
>
> That said, there are two main reason our sample code tends to always use “using” or dispose the context in some other way:
>
> 1. The default automatic open/close behavior is relatively easy to override: you can assume control of when the connection is opened and closed by manually opening the connection. Once you start doing this in some part of your code, then forgetting to dipose the context becomes harmful, because you might be leaking open connections.
> 2. DbContext implements IDiposable following the recommended pattern, which includes exposing a virtual protected Dispose method that derived types can override if for example the need to aggregate other unmanaged resources into the lifetime of the context.

So basically, unless you are managing the connection, or have a specific need to dispose it, it's safe to not do it.

I'd still recommend disposing it, of course, but in case you don't see where it'd be a good time to do it, you may just not do it at all.

Comment: I'm sorry if the explanation sounds lengthy and convoluted. I have it pretty clear in my mind, but English is not my native language and tonight I'm having a hard time being concise!

Comment: First of all thank you for your effort, long answers are good and your english is great. By registering context and repositories PerLifetimeScope I am suppossed to get a *new* context and repositories for each request, am I wrong?? I'd really like to keep the code as close as possible to this one, therefore I'd rather dispose the context. Disposing the context at the end of unit of work or at the end of request is similar to my understanding

Comment: I'm based on this line of your question: `calling the GetFolders method works the first time, and afterwards fails`. I don't know how your http calls are made, but it's perfectly possible that, if your lifetimescope is only being created on application startup, the http request is not actually creating a new application but reusing an existing one? If so (you'd need to test that), you may want to use a `using container.BeginLifetimeScope()` on each of your `DataService` methods

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Autofac automatically creates a lifetime scope for each request, I'm so confused :( I don't want to expose Autofac to any component other than my Startup

Comment: Well, that's easy to test: create a string property on the `DbContext` and set it to something on the first past... then debug and make a breakpoint on the second request before setting the property: if that property is set to that `something`, then AutoFac is obviously reusing it. Should be a simple check to at least know where the problem lies: if that's the problem, then you may find a solution for that, but we need to be sure.

Comment: Will check that first thing tomorrow. Is there any reason for not creating new lifetime scopes? Any code I'm missing here? If this is the problem how can it be solved?

Comment: Well, I don't know your specifics, but *conceptually* you don't open a web application each request: you have one application that may handle many requests. I'm not sure how you are using the AutoFac container (and as I specified in my first comment, I've never used AutoFac), but if you are creating it on application startup (and not per-request), and you are not setting a specific lifetime-scope, then it makes sense that you only get one per-application, and not per-request. As how to solve... well, you solve it creating a lifetime-scope per-request... there are possibly many ways to do it

Comment: Seems AutoFac does have a per-request scope indeed, here's the link to the docs: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html . You may need to carefully read the docs about that, I can't help with it: I don't do any web with .NET (I do it in other platforms though) and only have a very basic understanding of how .NET webapps work, and I don't use AutoFac (I've used other DI containers, but not specifically AutoFac). In your case, giving it a -very quick- read to the doc, it seems that changing `InstancePerLifetimeScope` to `InstancePerRequest` should actually do the trick.

Comment: (at least if you are doing WebApi or MVC, which seems you are)